# How do I handle null_glob results in fish?

Tags: fish

I have a fish function that contains the following `rm` statement:

```
rm ~/path/to/dir/*.log
```

This statement works fine if there are *.log files in that path, but fails when there are no *.log files. The error is:

```
~/.config/fish/functions/myfunc.fish (line 5): No matches for wildcard '~/path/to/dir/*.log'. See `help expand`.
    rm ~/path/to/dir/*.log
       ^
in function 'myfunc'
        called on standard input
```

ZSH has what are called [Glob Qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). One of them, `N`, handles setting the NULL_GLOB option for the current pattern, which essentially does what I want:

> If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, delete the
>   pattern from the argument list instead of reporting an error.

I understand that fish doesn't have [ZSH-style glob qualifiers](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2680), but I am unclear how to handle this scenario in my fish functions. Should I be looping through an array? It seems really verbose. Or is there a more fishy way of handling this scenario?

```
# A one-liner in ZSH becomes this in fish?
set -l arr ~/path/to/dir/*.log
for f in $arr
    rm $f
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fish does not support rich globs, [but `count`, `set`, and `for` are special](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand) in that they nullglob. So you could write:

```
set files ~/path/to/dir/*.log; rm -f $files
```

(The `-f` is required because `rm` complains if you pass it zero arguments.)

`count` could also work:

```
count ~/path/to/dir/*.log >/dev/null && rm ~/path/to/dir/*.log
```

For completeness, a loop:

```
for file in ~/path/to/dir/*.log ; rm $file; end
```

Comment: `count ~/path/to/dir/*.log >/dev/null ;and rm ~/path/to/dir/*.log` seems like a good option without the need for loops or extra variables. Works great. Thank you!