# fish shell: rm with wildcard and not found files

Tags: fish

Is there a way to use `fish` with a command like

```
rm -rf *.pdf *.gz
```

although no `pdf` files are available? Currently I get the response

```
fish: No matches for wildcard '*.pdf'. See `help expand`.
```

I found for the zsh the possibilty to set `setopt +o nomatch` but this isn't recognized in `fish` shell. Using Version 3.0.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle null\_glob results in fish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720232/how-do-i-handle-null-glob-results-in-fish)

Comment: Hmmm... I'm little bit unclear how I can use it for multiple wild card, like in my sample above with two. But I have finally 6 or 7 different file extensions which I want delete all at once. Therefore I don't say the two questions are same.

Comment: The advice is sound: `set files *.{pdf,gz,txt,xml}` (or, whatever your extensions are) will find the files you want.

Comment: The advice works and I agree that the referred solution is a very good starting point. Nevertheless I see this issue little bit different. In the referred solution it is not an issue to handle multiple files. Additionally one needs to know that `null_glob` is the keyword one needs to search. Make an answer here and I'll accept it - no problem.